# Closing Microsoft 365 tenant while keeping mailboxes open in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, azure, azure-activedirectory

I have migrated two Office 365 tenants. 3 users from tenant 1 already had an account in tenant 2   so I didn't migrated their mailboxes because they already have one in the new tenant 2 but they want to keep the tenant 1 mailbox archive available in their Outlook because they need the emails they have in there. Tenant 1 will be closed as soon as possible.

How can I do that without have them loosing all their email? Perhaps I should deactivate the users accounts first, so they stop sync with Exchange online, then delete their account from Ms 365 Admin?

Comment: Why can’t they make a copy of each email and place them on a local .PST and optionally also copy them to their new mailbox?

Comment: Why don't you just export their data as in tenant 1 to a PST and then you can either attach as an archive if they are using Outlook or import it in to the new tenant somewhare.

Comment: @Ziggy32 because their mailbox is bigger than 20gb, I noticed when I export the PST from tenant 1 it split in 10gb files, so I end having 2 - 3 PST which I don't think can be imported in Outlook as a single mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's actually easy to export the data to a local .pst in Outlook client(File> Open & Export> Import/Export>Export to a file), and you could import the file to another account or open it directly in Outlook.
[image]

Comment: I thought about that (silly me), I should be able to try today. Thank you :)